# How do I compile using the nightly build of the Solidity compiler

Tags: solidity, remix

Using the Remix IDE, I'd like to try out some of the new features of Solidity by using the nightly compiler build, but it's giving me a wrong compiler error.

When I try

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

//...
```

while using version 0.6.0-nightly.2019.3.11+commit.4704ef84.Emscripten.clang

I get the error: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.0-nightly.2019.3.11+commit.4704ef84.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

trying `pragma solidity ^0.5.7;` works but then I cant try the new features.

Comment: Does `pragma solidity >0.5.8 <0.6.0;` work? (Though I notice there's not actually a `0.5.8` release yet... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just to ensure the answer in the comments doesn't go missing at some point.)

You should be able to do this using:

`pragma solidity >0.5.8 <0.6.0;`

The error is basically saying that a nightly `0.6.0-nightly.xxx...` isn't actually `0.6.0` proper (i.e. `0.6.0` doesn't actually exist yet). So you want to force the use of something lower than `0.6.0`, but higher than the previous major version.